# How can I find the rate of change in the rate of change in density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow

[image]

Using the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics, do an  energy balance on this tank to determine the temperature and pressure (and density) as a function of the amount of air that has left the tank.

This is the problem i have trouble with. I’ve tried many way until i got this. But after calculation, I realized that $ln|0|$ is undefined. How can I solve this problem?

[image]